# username and password retrieval for ZyXEL router?

Tags: networking, router, adsl

I don't have the username and password for a ZyXEL Prestige 650H/HW 33 router device which I want to access because I'm moving to another ISP. Is there any solution, other than hardware reset which causes all configuration settings be reset to factory defaults, to retrieve username and password?

Related question: Would I have any issues to deal with if i go for a physical reset? Cause there's a whole LAN behind that router `:)`

Sorry, I'm not a sys/net admin, just trying to figure out what to do. Any help please?

Comment: Do you mean the default username and password?

Comment: i wish it was that buddy! The username and password have been changed from defaults to some other unknown to me at the moment, by some other previous administrator.

Comment: When getting hardware from someone else, the usual way is to reset it. Is anything wrong with that?

Comment: Who said that it's wrong? it's what i thought too! If there's a way to kinda "hack" them from inside the LAN, why to get into the reset thing and loose all the current configuration settings. I guess it's crystal clear what i'm saying.

Comment: The best way to "cause all configuration settings be reset to factory defaults" is to press the physical reset button. Is there any specific reason preventing you from doing that? If so, please add this to the question content.

Comment: You where right i edited the question, it was wrong..: )

Answer (score 3):

[Zyxel Router Passwords](http://portforward.com/default_username_password/ZyXEL.htm)

Maybe that link can help. Just reset the router and use the standard one.

Comment: That would be my last possible choice! Reseting the router will cause all settings to be restored to factory defaults (credentials for internet access will probably be lost too!)

Comment: @Michalis: You're moving to a new ISP, so you'll get new credentials anyway, aren't you? The previous credentials are not yours, so why do you want to keep them?

Comment: @Thomas: I guess you're right about that.. but it's more, behind the router there's a whole LAN, so i'm not sure if reseting the router it's gonna raise issues to other HW. You see i'm not an sys/net admin just trying to figure out what to do :)